# Code not compiling in javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't write in javascript but my friend asked me if I can help him with one kata (https://www.codewars.com/kata/ascii-fun-number-1-x-shape/)
I gave him this code, but i have no idea why it's not working, I'm totally newbie in javascript, can someone tell me what I did wrong :D?
Error message:
The server timed out waiting for the code to finish executing. It is possible that this is due to high server load. It may also be caused by inefficent code. Please try your request again.

```
function x(n)
{
  printlines(n);
  print("\n");
  for(column = 0; column < n; column++)
  {
    if(column = 1) 
    {
      print("■");
    }
    else
    {
      print("□");
    }
  }
  print("\n");
  printlines(n);
}


function print(n)
{
  console.log(n);
}  

function printlines(n)
{
  i = 1;
  for(line = 0; line < 1; line++)
  {
    for(column = 0; column < n; column++)
    {
      if(column = line)
      {
        print("■");
      }
      else if( column = n - 1)
      {
        print("■");
      }
      else
      {
        print("□");
      }
     }
     print("\n");
     i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not a compiled language. Are you trying to execute the code and fails, or does it fail to produce the right answer? Can you provide a little more information regarding the problem that you are facing?

Comment: _"can someone tell me what I did wrong"_ - didn't you say that yourself already? You are trying to "help" someone with something you do not have the first clue about yourself. No how's that supposed to work, I wonder?

Comment: Error message: The server timed out waiting for the code to finish executing. It is possible that this is due to high server load. It may also be caused by inefficent code. Please try your request again

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `var column` to declare it ( same in i and line )  in your loop `for` , and in your `if` u have to write `==` instead of `=` (`==` to test equality )

Comment: Now it says "Failed to process output. It is possible that too much data was written to STDOUT."

Comment: Are you executing `x(n)` ?  And which value u give to n ? Simply : which function do you execute ?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use http://jslint.com to help me validate my JavaScript. But right off of the bat, I can tell you that you need to declare the vars that you are using to iterate in your for loops and in JavaScript you use "==" or "===" for comparison.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.